# Characterization of equivalence of multicategories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, equivalence-of-categories

Consider the well-known categorical result:

> **Theorem 1.5.9** (of [Riehl's book](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/context.pdf)). A functor defining an equivalence of categories is full, faithful, and essentially surjective on objects. Assuming the axiom of choice, any functor with these properties defines an equivalence of categories.

I was wondering if the formal counterpart of this result in multicategories is also true. For a definition of a multicategory, a multifunctor and a natural transformation of multifunctors, see [this](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6117/2020sp/Lectures/Multicategories.pdf), pp. 1, 2, 4, respectively. Define an *isomorphism of multifunctors* to be a natural transformation of multifunctors whose components are all isomorphisms. Now one can generalize Definition 1.5.4 of Riehl's book to

> **Definition.** An *equivalence of multicategories* consists of multifunctors $F:\mathsf{C}\leftrightarrows\mathsf{D}:G$ together with natural isomorphisms $\eta:1_\mathsf{C}\cong GF$, $\epsilon:FG\cong 1_\mathsf{D}$.

So under all of these definitions, my first question is: does Theorem 1.5.9 generalize to multicategories? Or is there something that may fail? I don't have the time right now to delve into higher abstractions by trying to generalize myself Riehl's proof. So my second question is: is the proof already written in some book or does the result show up somewhere in the literature?

Comment: can't you just mimick the proof in Riehl's book?

Comment: @DanielTeixeira With "I don't have the time right now to delve into higher abstractions" I meant that right now I don't have the time to check if everything in that proof still works in the multicategorical case. I don't think I would gain much insight from such a proof, and in case there is some obstruction and the proof actually does not generalize, I wanted to know.